# CUDA - thrust::sort on device returns only 0's

Tags: c++, sorting, cuda, thrust

I have run the following Thrust example for sorting. The problem is that after the `thrust::sort`, the output contains all `0`'s.

Please, tell me what is wrong here.

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>    
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{

    thrust::host_vector<int> h_vec(32 << 20);
    thrust::generate(h_vec.begin(), h_vec.end(), rand);


    thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec=h_vec;

    for(int i = 0; i<32;i++)
        cout<<d_vec[i]<<endl;

    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    thrust::sort(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end());

    for(int i = 0; i<32;i++)
        cout<<d_vec[i]<<endl;

    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl; 

    thrust::copy(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end(), h_vec.begin());


    for(int i = 0; i<32;i++)
        cout<<h_vec[i]<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a *complete* code (why eliminate the `#include` statements?  That just makes it harder for others to help you.) Please also identify the GPU you are running on and the compile command you are using.  Your code runs fine for me, the complete example is [here](http://pastebin.com/a6N5JrYJ).  There may be a problem with the machine you are trying to run it on, or your compile command may be wrong for the GPU you are using.

Comment: #include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "iostream"

these are the include statements

Comment: The GPU is GT 610
 And I am using runtime library Multi-Threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)

Comment: @RobertCrovella By `32 << 20`, the OP is generating `33554432` random numbers, but displaying only the first `32`. I suspect that what he is observing is that the first `32` sorted numbers are just `0`. I have tested the OP's code on two Windows 7 systems, both equipped with CUDA 5.5, but using two different cards (GT210 and GT540M having cc 1.2 and 2.1, respectively) and I see the same effect, which disappears when `32 << 20` is changed to `32`. In the latter case, I see non-zero numbers. What I do not understand is why you are not observing the same.

Comment: @JackOLantern you've identified the issue. `rand()` returns a number in the range of 0..`RAND_MAX` On my 64-bit linux machine, RAND_MAX is 2^31-1.  On a 32-bit windows machine, `RAND_MAX` is 2^15-1 (32767). (I haven't tested a 64-bit windows machine, but [it would appear to be 32767 also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dfe3bzd.aspx)). When RAND_MAX is much larger than 32<<20, then we have a small population of zeros in the produced field of numbers. But when RAND_MAX is much smaller than 32<<20, we have a large population of zeros, which show up at the beginning of the sorted output.

Comment: @JackOLantern if you want to add an answer, please do, I'll upvote.  A simple mod can be made to the program to choose the smaller of (32<<20, RAND_MAX) for the data size, and it will give understandable results on linux and windows, I think.  Presumably the code was originally written with linux in view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are observing all `0`'s is that you are generating a large number of random numbers, i.e., `32 << 20 = 33554432`, between `0` and `RAND_MAX`, you are orderning them, but you are displaying only `32` of them.

As mentioned by Robert Crovella, on a Windows machine (the OP is working on Windows), `RAND_MAX = 2^15-1 = 32767`. Accordingly, you are generating `33554432` integers between `0` and `32767`, which means that you will have a large number of `0`'s in the original array and so all `0`'s in the first `32` numbers of the sorted array.

I have personally verifyed that this occurs for both, Windows `32` and `64` bit machines, that is, on both Windows `32` and `64` bit systems `RAND_MAX = 32767`.

Again, as pointed out by Robert, this effect will show on Linux `32` bit machines, but not on Linux `64` bit machines, for which `RAND_MAX = 2^31-1` since, for that case, `RAND_MAX` is much larger than `32 << 20`.

As suggested by Robert, one may change the instruction

```
thrust::host_vector<int> h_vec(32 << 20);
```

to

```
thrust::host_vector<int> h_vec(min(32 << 20,RAND_MAX));
```

to avoid the all `0`'s show.